# Create dictionary {(row, column): cell value} from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

From a given dataframe, I am trying to create a dictionary with the following format: `{(row, column):'cell value'}`. I am aware of `pandas.DataFrame.to_dict`, but that creates a dictionary of dictionaries: `{row:{column:'cell value'}}`.

Would you have any code suggestions? Would loop be a good idea?

Answer (score 2):

You could loop over the rows and columns and use `.loc` to get the corresponding value.

```
{(row, col): df.loc[row, col] for row in df.index for col in df.columns}
```

For demonstration, if `df` is:

```
            max_speed  shield
cobra               1       2
viper               4       5
sidewinder          7       8
```

The result is:

```
{('cobra', 'max_speed'): 1,
 ('cobra', 'shield'): 2,
 ('viper', 'max_speed'): 4,
 ('viper', 'shield'): 5,
 ('sidewinder', 'max_speed'): 7,
 ('sidewinder', 'shield'): 8}
```

*[This `df` is from the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).]*

Answer (score 0):

Take the result of `to_dict` and create a new dict:

```
result = {}
for column, inner_dict in df.to_dict().items():
    for row, value in inner_dict.items():
        result[(row, column)] = value
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code it's makeing  your data fram to list of dictionary's

```
Panda.DataFrame.to_dict(orient="records")
```

Then using a for loop